# Problems with terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

My terminal now looks like this:

[Today's terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBw1x.png)

But yesterday my terminal was ok and it looked like this:

[old terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WloLA.png)

So I would like to have the old terminal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `settings.json`

and then

```
"terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true
```

You just have to turn it `false`